# Observable.of does not work as expected in HttpClient Interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

#### Problem

The `Observable.of` convert arguments to an observable sequence means it can be used as a mock response to another Observable which is subscribe.
But now, It seems `Observable.of` does not work when its called from an interceptor because methods which are subscribing to it does not execute

#### Expected behavior:

When Observable.of is called with the given data, the `HttpClient` should return the data to the method which is already subscribing to it

#### Demo

**[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8j63yr)**  (open DevTools console to read logs)

There is a service (`mock.service.ts`) which makes a mock HTTP get request using `HttpClient`, the request arrives at `mock.interceptor.ts` and it want's to answer with the mock data using `Observable.of` (means wants to not let the request to goes over the network), the `mock.service` has a subscriber in `app.component` which is waiting for the response of the `HttpClient`. No data arrives in subscriber, nor error.

Any idea about how to implement interceptor that works with `Observable.of`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the return statement in interceptor intercept method to:

```
return Observable.of( new HttpResponse<any>( { body: mockData }))
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjv9m8)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please update the provided demo with your idea?

Comment: It would be nice if you can edit your answer and explain more about the reason that I had this problem

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.of` is depricated use `Observable.create` instead

```
return Observable.create((ob) => {
      ob.next(new HttpResponse<any>({body: data}));
});
```